# How can I record a desktop sharing session in Lync?

Tags: screen-recorder, lync-2013

When I have accepted someone's request to share their screen with me using Lync 2013, it displays their screen in the staging area as you would expect.

How can I use Lync 2013 to save the screen sharing session for future reference?

After some research, it appears that [Peer to Peer](http://blogs.technet.com/b/nexthop/archive/2011/08/11/confpoliciesenablep2precording.aspx) recording must be enabled for this to work at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The record button is hidden behind some ellipses (...).

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/lync-help/record-and-play-back-a-lync-meeting-HA102809287.aspx

Answer (score 2):

To call someone and record the session, highlight the person you want to call, then hit the cog and do meet now.  This is like a conference call.  If you just want to record yourself, then just call yourself.

[image]

and then press the ... and Start Recording

[image]

Don't forget to Stop Recording when you're done

and set screen recording to High Def before you do your recordings

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually usually is not easy as the answer...

Check this blog: http://ucken.blogspot.ca/2010/11/lync-call-recording.html
To understand the process that even require some changes on the Lync Server